# Is there any way to scan qr code only once?

Tags: flutter, dart

while scannin a qr code it gives result twice and scan qr code twice , it should only scan once , but after pausing camera it just scans the same code twice . how to fix this?

```
 StreamSubscription<Barcode> qrListener(
      QRViewController controller, BuildContext context) {
    return controller.scannedDataStream.listen((event)  async{
       await  controller.pauseCamera();
        String? url = event.code;
        log('$url');
```

```
[log] Instance of 'Barcode'
D/CameraPreview(22691): pause()
D/CameraInstance(22691): Closing camera
D/SensorManager(22691): unregisterListener ::
[log] http://hello
D/DecoderThread(22691): Found barcode in 80 ms
D/CameraInstance(22691): Camera is closed, not requesting preview
[log ] Instance of 'Barcode'
[log] http://hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added a counter and increment when listener is active , so when the value is 1
, add your code using if else

```
int counter =0;

 StreamSubscription<Barcode> qrListener(
      QRViewController controller, BuildContext context) {
    return controller.scannedDataStream.listen((event)  async{
       counter++;
       await  controller.pauseCamera();
     
        String? url = event.code;
        log('$url');

      if(counter==1){
            
//your code here//

                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also set the last date

```
void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
this.controller = controller;
var lastQrCodeReadDate = DateTime.now();

controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
  final dateNow = DateTime.now();

  if (dateNow.difference(lastQrCodeReadDate).inSeconds < 3) return;

  await controller.pauseCamera();

  try {
    final code = scanData.code;
    if (code == null) {
      throw Exception('Empty qrcode code');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }

  lastQrCodeReadDate = DateTime.now();
  await controller.resumeCamera();
});
```

}